# Recursive SELECT from Postgres table to replace ID with its NAME

Tags: postgresql, select

I have a table with the reference to itself "parent_id": 
`id, name, parent_id`

How can I replace parent_id with its name or display it in the new column?

I've tried to use Recursive SELECT but it doesn't solve my problem:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recordTMP AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id  FROM record WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
        UNION 
    SELECT R.id, R.name, R.parent_id FROM record R JOIN recordTMP T ON T.parent_id=R.id
) SELECT * FROM recordTMP;
```

Data sample:

```
1   Earth       (null)
2   Europe      1
3   Africa      1
4   France      2
5   Spain       2
6   Egypt       3
7   Paris       4
8   Madrid      5
9   Australia   (null)
```

I expect to be:

```
ID  NAME        PARENT_ID  <PARENT_NAME>
1   Earth       (null)     (NULL)
2   Europe      1          'Earth'
3   Africa      1          'Earth'
4   France      2          'Europe'
5   Spain       2          'Europe'
6   Egypt       3          'Africa'
7   Paris       4          'France'
8   Madrid      5          'Spain'
9   Australia   (null)     (NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it from the joined table using `t.name` in the second select. But as both parts of the union need to have the same number of columns you will have to add a `null` value in the first select:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recordTMP AS (
    SELECT id, created, name, parent_id, null::text as parent_name
    FROM record 
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT R.id, R.created, R.name, R.parent_id, t.name
    FROM record R 
      JOIN recordTMP T ON r.parent_id = t.id
) 
SELECT * 
FROM recordTMP;
```

Your query has two other errors:

1. you are selecting the wrong rows in the anchor part: you want to get all those *without* a parent there - those are selected with `parent_id IS NULL` (nor `IS NOT NULL`)
2. your recursive join was the wrong way round.

Online example: https://rextester.com/MVFBDK19855